# Можно ли слиять несколько отличающихся веток в одну?

Tags: github

Вообщем у нас командный проект (мы пишем разные подпрограммы) основываясь не ветке мастер.Можно ли каждую подпрограмму слиять с общей?

Comment: Вы хотите в результате получить мастер с двумя подпрограммами? Можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Ветки для того и созданы, чтобы их при необходимости сливать друг с другом.

Comment: Так нет если конфликт ну т.е есть основная программа ты добавил одну допустим функцию,затем твой напарник добавил независимую от неё процедуру можно ли это слиять разом? Без конфликтов. И у всех отличается от default master, если добавит 1 то тогда получит конфликт второй и наоборот.

Comment: "Сливать ветки" и "сливать ветки без конфликтов" это совсем не одно и то же. Как вы хотите слить без конфликтов, если у вас, допустим, в одной и той же строчке разные изменения?

Comment: нет например у каждого по одной подпрограмме разной которой нету в default master.

Comment: Да, можно. В чем вообще у вас проблема?

Comment: Ну если сольёт сначала 1 то будут отличие (мб можно сливать 2 ветки сразу) только недавно познакомился с github.

Comment: Отличие чего с чем будет? Почитайте руководство. Вы задаете вопросы, на которые там уже есть ответы.

Comment: Отличие ветки одного человека с исходной т.к другой уже отгрузил свои изменения.

Comment: И что дальше-то? Сливать можно. Если возникают конфликты - их придется решать, и скорее в его вручную. В чем вопрос?

Comment: так а если решать то как? чтобы 1 слил свою с master тогда он потеряет свои изменения.Если по другому никак то просто напишете что никак.

Comment: Я же написал как - вручную. Ни я, ни гит не можем знать, какие изменения нужно оставить. Если в одной ветке написано х=2, а в другой х=5, то откуда гит знает, что из этого должно попасть в мастер? Решить это можете только вы.

Comment: ок, понял спасибо.